# Getting Null values in form collection in ASP.Net MVC while submitting using ajax. What can be issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save data using ajax call. But in action result i am getting null values of Model.

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addaboutftw", "AboutFtw", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", @id = "addaboutftw_frm", @name = "addaboutftw_frm" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.title, new { @for = "title", @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.title, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "FTW from The Start" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id, new { @class = "form-control",@placeholder = "FTW from The Start" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.detail_contents, new { @for = "detail_contents", @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.detail_contents, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Content in Detail" })
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_save" name="btn_save">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**jQuery Ajax**

```
$("#btn_save").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/AboutFtw/addaboutftw",
      data: $("#addaboutftw_frm").serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
       alert(data.Message);
      }
   });
 });
```

**Action Result**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addaboutftw(AboutFtwViewModel model)
  {
         int result=0;
         AboutFtw dbaboutftw = new AboutFtw();
         dbaboutftw.title = model.title;
         dbaboutftw.detail_contents = model.detail_contents ;
         result = _ftwCommonMethods.AboutFtwAdd(dbaboutftw);
         return Json(new { Message = result.ToString() });
 }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class AboutFtwViewModel{
   public Int64 id { get; set;}
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   [Display(Name = "Title")]
   public string title { get; set; }
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   [Display(Name = "Content in Detail")]
   public string detail_contents { get; set; }
}
```

What can be issue? Am i missing anything? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you using `FormCollection`? Change your POST method to `public ActionResult addaboutftw(AboutFtw model)` and it will be correctly bound.

Comment: And why are your adding `new { @for = "name" }`? The `LabelFor()` method already adds the correct `for` attribute

Comment: and what would be in data:? instead of data: $("#addaboutftw_frm").serialize()?

Comment: Exactly what your doing now. But why do you have `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id)` when you dont even appear to use it in the POST method. And why does it have `@placeholder = "FTW from The Start"`? (its hidden!)And why do you generate a control for property `name` but then try to assign it to property `title`? Sorry, but not a lot of this code makes much sense

Comment: Tried addaboutftw(AboutFtw model) but still getting nll values

Comment: Show your model. If you have public getters and setters, you model will be correctly bound.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want use hidden field for edit purpose. it will come in later part. Now i just want to save a record. and i am getting null values.

Comment: And how are you triggering the ajax call? You don't even appear to have a button in your view.

Comment: Updated my code please see @StephenMuecke

Comment: Are you actually hitting your controller method? The code you have shown will work fine and the parameter `model` will be correctly bound.

Comment: i am sure @StephenMuecke

Comment: You last edit shows a model named `AboutFtwViewModel` yet your POST method parameter is `AboutFtw`.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs perfectly. I think you just made a syntax error in your Javascript, please edit it as follows:

```
$("#btn_save").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/About",
        data: $("#addaboutftw_frm").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Message);
        }
    })
});
```

You missed a closed parenthesis and the semicolon

Comment: Sorry missed to give those. But in my code those are there. But still getting null.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public class AboutFtwViewModel{
  public Int64 id { get; set;}
  [DataType(DataType.Text)]
  [Display(Name = "Title")]
  public string title { get; set; }
  [DataType(DataType.Text)]
  [Display(Name = "Content in Detail")]
  public string detail_contents { get; set; }
}
```

to:

```
public class AboutFtw{
   public Int64 id { get; set;}
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   [Display(Name = "Title")]
   public string title { get; set; }
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   [Display(Name = "Content in Detail")]
   public string detail_contents { get; set; }
}
```

Your view model is named differently to the model that you are passing to the controller.